# stored procedure in mysql, cannot figure out the syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

this is my proc, and below is my error, apart form the numerous `;` missing, what am I Missing on line 2??

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertOnReject
@id int
AS 
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE content_manager.submission SET state = 'Rejected' WHERE id = @id;

INSERT INTO content_manager.submission_rejected
    (id int,link_initial varchar,email varchar,id_category int ,state varchar,link_final varchar,ip_sub int ,sub_date datetime) 
SELECT
    submission.id, submission.link_initial, submission.email, submission.id_category, submission.state, submission.link_final, submission.ip_sub, submission.sub_date
FROM
    content_manager.submission
WHERE content_manager.submission.id = @id
COMMIT;
END
```

```
#1064 - Syntax error in the query SQL near '@id int
AS
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION' line 2
```

i really don't understand what syntax error am I missing, pls help

P.S: I'm doing my proc on phpMyAdmin, if that changes something...

Using [@Arulkumar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67571457/2451726), the error shifts :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertOnReject
(
    IN id int
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE content_manager.submission SET state = 'Rejected' WHERE id = @id;

    INSERT INTO content_manager.submission_rejected
    (id, link_initial, email, id_category, state, link_final, ip_sub, sub_date) 
    SELECT submission.id, submission.link_initial, submission.email, submission.id_category, submission.state, submission.link_final, submission.ip_sub, submission.sub_date
    FROM content_manager.submission
    WHERE content_manager.submission.id = @id;
    
COMMIT;
END
```

the error:

```
#1064 - Syntax error in the query SQL near '' line 6
```

still no solution

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) for syntax: `CREATE [DEFINER = user] PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...`

Comment: is @id is a input parameter? if it is then  it should be wrapped around the parenthesis likeCREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertOnReject
(IN inp_id int). What MYSQL version you are using and posting ddl and dml will help to fix the query further.

Comment: wrapping it inside the parenthesis didn't change anything, same error on the same line, my mysql is at 8.0 version

Comment: Why do you try to put `as` between procedure header and procedure body? I've provided you a link, there are a syntax and a lot of examples there.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @astentx using the `AS` isn't the problem, the examples you provided in the documentation don't use it, but I don't think the use of `AS`  is the issue, anyway I gave it a try and it moved the error to something more unusual: Syntax error in the query SQL near '' line 4

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is just the syntax, the fact that is giving me an error on that line and that is a syntax error is odd for me, since I don't see it, it could be a really really easy fix, but I don't know what to fix

Comment: Why do you think *as is not a problem*? [It is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84f70ed0f1a96f34a440704bd98d9893). You have a lot of syntax errors in your query, so please remove all and add statement by statement to the procedure

Comment: There's no type definitions in insert statement of @Arulkumar, please try copypasted text. Also this answer has a link with successfully compiling code, so it cannot be *not working*

Comment: @GabrieleBattistata My updated answer was with out the `@` in the `@id`, have you tried that? Please refer the demo link.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the procedure [with out any error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a83ca9626a89c242002d49b6eecfae76). There are lot of issues in your procedure.

- Parameter declaration,
- `AS` added,
- Insert into variable contain the data type,
- missed semi colon.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertOnReject
(
    IN InputId int
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE content_manager.submission SET state = 'Rejected' WHERE id = InputId;

    INSERT INTO content_manager.submission_rejected
    (id, link_initial, email, id_category, state, link_final, ip_sub, sub_date) 
    SELECT submission.id, submission.link_initial, submission.email, submission.id_category, submission.state, submission.link_final, submission.ip_sub, submission.sub_date
    FROM content_manager.submission
    WHERE content_manager.submission.id = InputId;
    
COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: I already known about the missing semi colon( as I wrote in my question), I gave it a shot with your solution, still an error, i will update the question to show it to you

Comment: @GabrieleBattistata If you know about semicolon, then why you post the question about what is the error? If you follow the *minimal* part of [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll easily locate the problematic place.

Comment: because the error is not the semicolon, since it wasn't needed in the line where it told me the error was found

Comment: `WHERE id = id` will apply the update to every row. How is SQL supposed to know the first id is a column in the table but the second id is the procedure parameter? It doesn't. It interprets both as the column in the table, so `id = id` will be true on every row. Solution: name your procedure parameters some other name that is not the same as any column of tables referenced in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

you copied your code from another database probably SQL SERVER. mysql handles such things different

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertOnReject
(IN_id int)

BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
SET @id = _id;
UPDATE content_manager.submission SET state = 'Rejected' WHERE id = @id;

INSERT INTO content_manager.submission_rejected
    (id ,link_initial ,email ,id_category ,state ,link_final ,ip_sub,sub_date) 
SELECT
    submission.id, submission.link_initial, submission.email, submission.id_category, submission.state, submission.link_final, submission.ip_sub, submission.sub_date
FROM
    content_manager.submission
WHERE content_manager.submission.id = @id;
COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No(?), I didn't

Comment: it looks like it , try i´mine solution if gives you no error